# Function not being recognized as a function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`store.changes` takes a function as an argument. `test` takes an object and its property as an argument:

```
store.changes(test(this, 'posts'))

function test (obj, prop) {
  store.find().then(posts => {
    obj[prop] = _.map(posts.rows, (post) => post.doc)
  })
}

store.changes = (func) => {
  return db.changes({
    since: 'now',
    live: true
  }).on('change', func)
}
```

But for some reason `store.changes` ins't recognizing `test(this, 'posts')` as a function, it throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: listener must be a function

Why is this?

Comment: `test(this, 'posts')` is not - does not return - a function?!

Comment: `test(this, 'posts')` change to `function(){ test(thisObj, 'posts'); }`

Comment: You are passing the result of a function, not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the result of a call, `undefined` - not a function. I believe you are looking for

```
store.changes(() => test(this, 'posts'));
```